# Identifying sub parts within sequence of text using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, object-detection

First of all I am very new to deep learning and sorry if I am not asking the questions that are not up to the standard of the site.

I have a sequence of `arm assembly opcodes` that are respective to a number of functions (You can view the whole `csv` file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bDDKG-han8qeNlIuLUQGCnnjn7E2yEH_/view?usp=sharing)). If I give a one particular sequence of a function it is as follows.

```
// This is the disassembly sequence of a function named bit()

// just assume four opcodes `b0 0a 46 01` belong to certain other library
83 b0 0a 46 01 90 02 a8 01 70 ff e7 01 98 01 68 01 22 52 05 91 43 01 60 02 a8 00 78 40 05 00 90 ff e7 01 98 01 68 00 9a 11 43 01 60 01 98 03 b0 70 47
```

I have already built a small deep learning model (by following a NLP tutorial) to classify among eight classes of function when a byte sequence as above is passed. However, what I need is in addition to identifying the function label, to identify the byte sequence that belong to particular library.For example, in the above function `b0 0a 46 01` believe to a different library. So I want to identify such sub sequences when a whole function sequence is passed. I believe it is similar to object detection in images where instead of just identifying the image itself, identifying the  objects in the model.

Frankly, I don't know whether such a requirement is possible in deep learning and if possible, I would like to know any resources/tutorials that I could look up and learn in order to reach my goal. Once again, sorry if I am asking something that doesn't make sense. Appreciate any help if possible.

Comment: I think deep learning would not be required for this, since assembly opcodes are in limited number with limited combination. Having said that, for this particular problem if you only consider text, problem is known as NER (Named Entity Recognition - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) problem. You will find many resources online for this.

Comment: @VivekMehta Thank you. NER is for word by word analysis right? For example, if it find a location it will be tagged as a location. however, here I need to consider a sequence of instructions (like 10-15) instead of one sequence.

Comment: NER is not limited to single word classification, It can classify sequence of words also.

Comment: @VivekMehta Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to consider this something like a object detection problem seems to make sense.  The Yolo model is supposed to be pretty decent in this use case:  https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/  .  Perhaps you can substitute 1D convolutions in place of the 2D convolutions to adapt to your use case.  Additionally, creating embeddings to encode your opcodes as a first step might be helpful, although you might have already implemented this part.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you think there is a possibility that I could do this in NLP. Is there any resources of previous work that you are aware with rather than image object detection?